# Обновить <div> отдельно от страницы AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Как по нажатию на кнопку обновить div? Именно обновить (***как при обновлении страницы по F5***), а не вписать туда заново то же самое. AJAX, JS, PHP

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Самое простое решение jQuery**

```
$("#block").load("index.php #block");
```

Этот код загрузит страницу `index.php` и поместит содержимое `#block` из загруженного документа в `#block` в текущем документе.

Легко реализовать на готовом проекте, но так делать неправильно, так как грузиться будет вся страница, и ajax не будет экономить ни трафик, ни вычислительные мощности.

Чтоб было правильно - у Вас должен быть контроллер на `ajax` запросы. К нему нужно обратиться и получить только нужную информацию. И по возможности - в json (например получить данные с голосования) и тогда использовать наиболее удобную функцию для подгрузки данных (`$.ajax`, `$.post`, `$.get`).

В тегах не было jQuery, но я рекомендую использовать его - без него будет довольно сложно реализовать задумку кроссбраузерно и красиво.

Comment: myzvar, ответ в принципе верный, но стоит его пояснить

Comment: @Etki, так нормально?

Comment: немного подредактировал